# decode characters to html using angularjs $sanitize

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to use $sanitize to decode characters but I'm running into a dilemma. I need to use the $sanitize service(I can't use ng-bind-html) but I seem to be getting two different outputs when I use $sanitize and ng-bind-html even though they are supposed to produce the same result since ng-bind-html goes through $sanitize.

Plnkr here http://plnkr.co/edit/IZPyVUO5zaTnxiIAzPLe?p=preview

Is there a way to get the value of the ng-bind-html output using the $sanitize service? Am I doing something stupid or is this a limitation of the angular implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `ng-bind-html` does not necessarily go through `$sanitize`. I think `ng-bind-html` is doing more than `$sanitize`, as `$sanitize` would only be one phase of `ng-bind-html` if it presents (called by `$sce`).

Accoring to `ng-bind-html`'s source code (bottom @ https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngBind.js), it is mainly using `$sce` for the conversion purpose. Something like this:

```
var ngBindHtmlDirective = ['$sce', '$parse', function($sce, $parse) {
  return function(scope, element, attr) {
    element.addClass('ng-binding').data('$binding', attr.ngBindHtml);

    var parsed = $parse(attr.ngBindHtml);
    function getStringValue() {
      var value = parsed(scope);
      getStringValue.$$unwatch = parsed.$$unwatch;
      return (value || '').toString();
    }

    scope.$watch(getStringValue, function ngBindHtmlWatchAction(value) {
      element.html($sce.getTrustedHtml(parsed(scope)) || '');
    });
  };
}];
```

The magic part should be `element.html($sce.getTrustedHtml(parsed(scope)) || '');`.

Comment: I see the difference now. But the trouble still remains. I dont have access to element and I'm trying to do this in a factory. Is that possible?

Comment: @dheerajmanju1 Ah ha, I think I've found the trick... You can put the sanitized html into a DOM element and then retrieve the text from it. Like: `angular.element('<div>'+$scope.sanitized+'</div>').text();` would produce exactly the same result as your `ng-bind-html`.